# Selecting rows with specific values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL. I've got my table with 3 columns. Given a list of values (lets say ints for example 1, 4, 3) I want to select rows in which the second columns value equals something that the given list contains.

Is it possible to pass a list as an argument in SQL?

```
select * from TABLE1 where ...
```

How do i finish this statement for it to work as i explained?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Sounds like a simple `where second_column in (1,2,3)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE col2 IN (1, 4, 3);
```

Most flavors of SQL support the `IN` clause, which allows comparing a column against a sequence of values.  In the query above, we compare `col2` against a collection of numbers, but we can equally compare against string literals, etc.

Comment: that did it, thank you!